# What is the best insulator for static charges?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, insulators

I am trying to find a solid material that almost fully (since there is not a thing that can fully insulate electricity) blocks static charges from one layer to another. I know plastic is a good insulator but I want to know if there is a better insulator than plastic. I am going to use this material as a clothing for a project so the material shouldn't be easily breakable like glass.

Comment: Only some types of glass are "easily breakable".  If you're going to make clothing you want something flexible and breathable.  Sounds like an engineering problem rather than a physics question.

Comment: This was crossposted elsewhere: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/126215/4512

Comment: @OlinLathrop Since the electrical engineering network is the correct place to discuss about I reposted it there. I think it is not abuse of rules.

Answer (score 0):

In practice clean plexiglass aka acrylic is an extremely good insulator for your purposes, assuming, that you want to do precision measurements, rather than  deal with high voltage power circuits, in which case you need to go with industrial ceramics for that purpose and maybe even immerse your circuit in oil. In any case, electrostatic shielding is as much a matter of geometry as it is of material choices. If you make sharp edges, points etc., then no material will help you, but if you do everything right using acrylic, your ultimate limit without radiation shielding will be cosmic rays. Basically, all electrostatic measurement devices end up as ionization chambers of sorts and it takes extreme measures (working in deep mines) to escape that background radiation.